# block scope accessing inner and outer variables

Tags: c++

I can't understand why variable 'xt'  and 'xs' accessing only inner parameter (xt=12, xs=23), when I printing this code first variable 'xy' gave inner and outer parameter( 10, 22) but rest of variable printing only inner parameters inside the block.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int xy=10;
   int xt=11;
   int xs=33;
   { int xy;
     xy=22;
     xt=12;
     xs=23;
     cout<<xy<<"  "<<xt<<" "<<xs<< endl;
   }
   cout<<xy<<"  "<<xt<<" "<<xs<< endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

The output is:

```
22  12 23
10  12 23
```

Comment: What do you mean printing only the inner parameters?  You only have one new variable in the inner scope (`xy`), so the other assignments are modifying variables in the outer scope.

Comment: Scoping considers _declaration_ of variables but not _assignment_.

Comment: Would have been clearer if you added the output and what you expected

Comment: In any question where you're asking about unexpected output, you should copy/paste into the question the output you get and the output you expect instead of "describing" those things.

Comment: -1 There's no reason to ever want to do this. If you want to create a new variable, name it differently. Don't make variables the same just to test C++. There's no ambiguity if you just name things differently and it solves your issue entirely.

Comment: quite surprising there isn't a duplicate found for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a brand *new* `xy` object in the inner scope that is totally unrelated to the one in the outer scope.

So *that's* the one that gets changed and printed in the inner scope.

However, the changes in the inner scope to `xt` and `xs` apply to the *outer* scope variables since there are no inner scope ones to hide them.

Here's what's actually happening:

```
int xy = 10;          // creates xy-outer.
int xt = 11;          // creates xt-outer.
int xs = 33;          // creates xs-outer.
{
    int xy;           // creates xy-inner.
    xy = 22;          // changes xy-inner.
    xt = 12;          // changes xt-outer.
    xs = 23;          // changes xs-outer.
    cout xy xt xs     // prints xy-inner and changed xt-outer/xs-outer
                      //   22, 12, 23
}
cout xy xt xs         // prints xy-outer and changed xt-outer/xs-outer
                      //   10, 12, 23
```

I often find it useful to think in terms of the C compiler searching the various scopes from inner to outer until it finds the first object with a matching name.

Answer (score 3):

`xy` inside the block is different than the `xy` in the function scope since you defined `xy` again inside the block with

```
int xy;
```

Consequently, when you modify `xy` in the block, you are not modifying the value of the variable of the same name in the function scope.

On the other hand, there is only one `xt` and and one `xs`. When you modify their values inside the block, you are modifying them for entire scope of the function, not just in the block scope.